# How to use Spring Security http pattern on Mule?

Tags: spring-security, mule

Im using spring security, but some parts without been secure and some with so i implemented http pattern for my paths,  but it doesnt appear to be working or even going through that part of the code...

Code done so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:servlet="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet"
xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:ssl="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet/current/mule-servlet.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/current/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.4/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.4/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.4/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.4/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl/current/mule-ssl.xsd" version="EE-3.4.0">

<mule-ss:security-manager> 
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="jdbc-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager"></mule-ss:delegate-security-provider>  
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<spring:beans> 
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" id="loggingInInterceptor" />
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" id="loggingOutInterceptor"/>

    <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
      <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>  
      <spring:property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>  
      <spring:property name="username" value="${database.user}"/>  
      <spring:property name="password" value="${database.pass}"/>
    </spring:bean>

    <ss:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex">
        <ss:intercept-url pattern="^/services/.*\.WSDL$" access="permitAll"/>
        <ss:intercept-url pattern="^/services/${webservice.idp.in.pessoas.path}" access="hasRole('ROLE_IDP')" />
        <ss:intercept-url pattern="^/services/${webservice.idp.in.setor.path}" access="hasRole('ROLE_IDP')" >
    </ss:http>

    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="
              select username, password, enabled 
              from users where username=?"

           authorities-by-username-query="
              select u.username, ur.authority from users u, authorities ur 
              where u.id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  "/>  
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>  
</spring:beans>

<https:connector name="httpsConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS"> 
    <https:tls-key-store path="${mule.home}/conf/keystore.jks" keyPassword="ciasc.123" storePassword="ciasc.123"></https:tls-key-store>  
</https:connector>

<scripting:transformer name="noopLoggingTransformer">
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        def props = [:]
        props['User-Agent'] = message.getProperty('User-Agent', org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INBOUND)
        props['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS'] = message.getProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS', org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INBOUND)
        props['http.request'] = message.getProperty('http.request', org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INBOUND)
        muleContext.client.dispatch('vm://log-request.in', payload, props)
        message        
     </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>

<pattern:web-service-proxy name="Logradouros2" transformer-refs="noopLoggingTransformer"  wsdlFile="AutenticacaoServico.wsdl">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="${serverName}/services/Logradouros/AutenticacaoServico" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="${targetServer}/servicos/v2/AutenticacaoServico.svc" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
</pattern:web-service-proxy>

<jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source name="WSA" user="${database.user}" password="${database.pass}" url="${database.url}" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source">
</jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source>

<jdbc-ee:connector name="jdbcConnector" dataSource-ref="WSA" validateConnections="false" transactionPerMessage="true" queryTimeout="10" pollingFrequency="10000" doc:name="JDBC"> 
    <jdbc-ee:query key="wsadb" value="insert into inbound_messages (payload, timestamp, agent, ip_from, endpoint, soap_operation) values ('', now(), #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('user-agent').toString()], #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').toString()], #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('http.request').toString()], '');"></jdbc-ee:query>  
</jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="log-request" doc:name="log-request"> 
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="log-request.in" />
    <logger message="#[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('user-agent').toString()], #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').toString()], #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('http.request').toString()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="wsadb" responseTimeout="10000" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Persist raw message" />
</flow>

</mule>
```

What is required to do to access that?
What i intend to do with that is access the wsdl file without login requirements, and the methods with...

Comment: I don't think Spring security HTTP rules can apply to Mule inbound HTTP endpoints.

Comment: And how can i disclosure the WSDL with no security and not the url it self, cause that was the only clue i had...

Comment: btw the same code works on an embebded version of mule 3.3, but im trying to push it into mulestudio and work on a standard 3.4 server, but that part (url pattern) is just not working... any clue?

Comment: No clue. I don't know what WSDL you're talking about. I can't imagine how `ss:intercept-url` can apply to a Mule endpoint (unless you run embedded in a servlet container?).

Comment: it is on a servlet container... the wsdl file is what i dont want to get blocked by the login:password from security, is that possible on Mule standard or its just not viable? the url i call is something like: http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/Logradouros/AutenticacaoServico?WSDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Mule's inbound HTTP endpoint, most of the Spring Security you have in place is useless. For example the `intercept-url` are not doing anything.

I suggest your look at the source code of `org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter` and extend it with your own code that will waive security for WSDL requests.

Then replace `<http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>` with your own version.

Comment: just did and still not working, it appears to not reach that code.

Comment: ive placed that into <ss:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex">

Comment: As it only child, and stil asking for login:password

Comment: OK, well, hopefully someone with Spring security experience will chime in, as it doesn't seem Mule related. I'm curious though: how is the Spring security filter configured in your web.xml file? How is your Mule web service configured? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: sure i will post the whole configuration and if you want you can try it with some services you make.

Comment: I don't think this can work: the `http:basic-security-filter` just does basic auth checking, it's Mule-specific. If you want the Spring security HTTP goodness to work, you need to use it in a web-app, configure it in web.xml and use Servlet not HTTP Mule endpoints.

Comment: Ok, too bad :/ Any way i will try using a servlet and see what it gives me :) tks!

Comment: Well i will leave this code the way it is and if one day mulesoft decide to cover that i will be happy if not, well did what i could in that matter :)

Comment: I reviewed my answer based on all the discussions in comments.